# Why threads are executing sequentially?

Tags: java, multithreading, java-threads

Q.1 I am trying to run two threads concurrently but here it is printing the value sequentially. For example it is printing 0 then 1 again 0 then 1. If threads are running concurrently then shouldn't it print like 0 0 then 1 1.

Q.2 it is giving output like 10, 11 then 0, 1, 0, 1. When it is printing 10 and 11 first. Does it mean that the threads t1 and t2 haven't started yet even though the program control goes to `t1.start()` and `t2.start()` first.

```
public class Main implements Runnable
{
    int x;

    public void run()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(x++);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Main());

        Thread t2 = new Thread(new Main());

        t1.start();
        t2.start();

        int y = 10;
        for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(y++);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no guarantee in which order threads will execute, so it is unpredictable in which order you will get output. It could be 0, 1, 0, 1 or 0, 0, 1, 1.

Comment: Basically when you talk about multi-threaded programs you can't predict how and when they are executed. Also you can't reason just using `println()` because it's buffered and does not reflect the execution of the program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `x` variable used by the Threads is not the same `x` variable that is printing within the `main` method.

As the code executed in the Threads is so short the first Thread will have finished by the time that the second thread has started

Also with this trivial example your code will be affected by the output buffer as well.

Comment: He edited out the `x` in the main method, so you may want to remove that part of your answer. I arrived after the edit and your answer confused me for a second.

Comment: @Michael Thanks for the heads-up.  After his edit I am not even sure that his question 2) makes any sense.

Comment: I edited because i didn't want to confuse you with 'x'.My 2nd question is that why it is printing 10 and 11 first when i called t1.start() and t2.start() before the loop in main thread.

Comment: Because there is a certain overhead is starting Threads and some time will pass in the Threads after control is passed back to `main` but before they start `working`

Comment: For one test on my machine main counts up to 260 before first thread starts. Then first thread works up to 768 and main up to 300, and in that moment second thread starts to work. As a side not it's good idea to print System.currentTimeMillis() and Thread.currentThread().getId() or similar time and thread info to be able to parse logs easier. It changes things in such short work scenarios, but in practice logging is not that excessive

Comment: I disagree when you say "As the code executed [...]". You can't be sure about this, it is unpredictable.

Comment: @BetaRunner Yes, maybe I should have said, *As the amount of code being executed in your example ...."*

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the concurrency in action, placing the sleep() method somewhere in the run method should help.